# How to prove $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arccos x}{\ln x}dx=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(2k-1)!!\ln(2k+2)}{2^k k! (2k+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Question:-Prove that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arccos x}{\ln x}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}-\frac {(2k-1)!!\ln(2k+2)}{2^k k! (2k+1)}$.

I have no idea how to prove this, If we use Taylor series of both $\arccos x$ and $\ln x $, then it is difficult to combine them. Also, Taylor series of $\frac {\arccos x}{\ln x}$ gives no help.

Can anybody help me to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have :
$$\arccos x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x=\arcsin 1-\arcsin x$$
And using Taylor series of $\arcsin$ we get :
$$\arccos x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!(2n+1)}(1-x^{2n+1})$$
Then we get :
$$\int_0^1\frac{\arccos x}{\ln x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!(2n+1)}\biggl(\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{\ln x}\biggr)$$
Therefore we put $x=e^{-t}$ so we have By Frullani Theorem :
$$\int_0^1\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{\ln x}=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-(2n+2)t}}{-t}=-\ln (2n+2) $$
Then we get the result.